# Draw Track on Map codenameone

Tags: java, android, gps, codenameone

I´m confused again, every time I tried to use code from Android Studio (java) on codename one I can´t obtain result.

CN1 is great, but I don´t understand how clone my projects from Android Studio there.

This is my situation: I want to create an Array with coordinates to draw the tracked route from the GPS on a MapComponent.

On Android Studio I create an ArrayList:

```
ArrayList< LatLng> points = new ArrayList< LatLng>();
```

and after that, I add the coordinates from the GPS every time the location is updated

```
points.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));
```

and finally I draw the line with the coordinates obtained

```
 PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions()

                .width(5)
                .color(Color.GREEN)
                .geodesic(true);
        polylineOptions.addAll(points);

        Polyline route = map.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
```

---

I want to use this procedure on CN1 I understand I should use LinesLayer()
I have this code from another post

```
LinesLayer l = new LinesLayer();
l.addSegment(coordinatesArray);
```

and then add the LineLayer to the map

```
mapComponent.addLayer(l);
```

(I´m not sure about this last line)

---

How I create the coordinateArray, and how add the line as layer on the MapComponent??

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try using Netbeans for this directly.

[MapComponent](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/maps/MapComponent.html) is a relatively simple component that is rather portable but doesn't use native maps on the device so it produces a sub par result.

I would suggest that you use the [Native Google Maps](https://github.com/codenameone/codenameone-google-maps/) support which includes better UI support.

Comment: Thanks, I´m already using NetBeans, so there is no create a track line with MapComponent?

Comment: There is and the general way you chose is correct but its a painful API. The native maps use it internally to work on the simulator so as you can see this is demo code for showing a path: https://github.com/codenameone/codenameone-google-maps/blob/master/GoogleMaps/src/com/codename1/googlemaps/MapContainer.java#L258-L280